# Use R style data in GraphPad Prism

Tags: r, statistics, dataformat

I am using R for my data analysis, but everyone else in my laboratory uses GraphPad Prism and I have been asked to present my data using that software as well.
In R I am used to handle my data in a "one observation per row" kind of way, so I might have data that look like

```
Sample  Gene    treatment   fold change
1       GBP1    no IFN      -0,11
2       GBP1    no IFN      -0,05
3       GBP1    no IFN       0,02
4       GBP1    IFN          300
5       GBP1    IFN          200
6       GBP1    IFN          400
1       GBP2    no IFN      -0,5
2       GBP2    no IFN      -0,55
3       GBP2    no IFN       0,3
4       GBP2    IFN          100
5       GBP2    IFN          140
6       GBP2    IFN          200
```

While Graphpad expects data to be structured like this

```
       no IFN 1    no IFN 2    no IFN 3    IFN 1    IFN 2    INF3
GBP1   -0,11       -0,05       0,02        300      200      400
GBP2   -0,5        -0,55       0,3         100      140      200
```

So I am wondering if anyone knows of a way to import the R style data to GraphPad Prism 8? I've failed converting it with R myself in a robust way.

Best

Niklas

Comment: Check the vignette (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_wider.html) for tidyr::pivot_wider().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `Sample` column, add a number for `treatment` column and then use `pivot_wider` to get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(-Sample) %>%
  group_by(Gene, treatment) %>%
  mutate(treatment = paste0(treatment, row_number())) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = treatment, values_from = fold_change)

# Gene  noIFN1 noIFN2 noIFN3 IFN1  IFN2  IFN3 
#  <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 GBP1  -0,11  -0,05  0,02   300   200   400  
#2 GBP2  -0,5   -0,55  0,3    100   140   200
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Sample = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L), Gene = c("GBP1", "GBP1", "GBP1", "GBP1", "GBP1", 
"GBP1", "GBP2", "GBP2", "GBP2", "GBP2", "GBP2", "GBP2"), treatment = c("noIFN", 
"noIFN", "noIFN", "IFN", "IFN", "IFN", "noIFN", "noIFN", "noIFN", 
"IFN", "IFN", "IFN"), fold_change = c("-0,11", "-0,05", "0,02", 
"300", "200", "400", "-0,5", "-0,55", "0,3", "100", "140", "200"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Wow that seems like the perfect way to do it! Thanks alot. Just one thing, when I tried to run the code, it cannot mutate treatment, because it is a grouping variable. But the code runs just finde using only Gene as a grouping variable.

Comment: Maybe create a new temporary variable `treatment1` i.e `df %>%
  select(-Sample) %>%
  group_by(Gene, treatment) %>%
  mutate(treatment1 = paste0(treatment, row_number())) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-treatment) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = treatment1, values_from = fold_change)`

Comment: Just a follow up question, my dataset is uneven at this stage, so I would have say two noIFN groups, and three IFN groups, how can I add a blank row to this NoIFN group? I have used a count function to determine which group has the highest number of rows initially, and my thoughts was to use a loop to see if the row number equals this number and if not, add a row. But I can't quite work it out.